# In how many ways you can write $2015$ as a $20x+15y$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In how many ways you can write $2015$ as a $20x+15y$ where $x$ and $y$ are natural numbers?

So probably I can do it using Euclid's algorithm but right now I am not sure how to do it. Could anyone explain step-by-step how to do exercises like this? I will be so grateful!

Comment: I take it that $x$ and $y$ are integer values (otherwise there are infinitely many ways)...?

Comment: @barakmanos I would also take them positive.

Comment: yes! sorry I forget to write it x,y are natural numbers

Answer (score 7):

To write $2015=20x+15y$ is the same as writing $403=4x+3y$. The latter can be solved by Euclidean algorithm or you can take a simple guess as $x=100$ and $y=1$. Once you get one solution then you can get infinitely many solutions (not necessarily incongruent) by using something like
$$403=4(100+3k)+3(1-4k), \qquad \text{ where } \, k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Oh, cool thanks! But how you found the last equality using this one solution?

Comment: @user210745 Suppose $403 = 4x + 3y$ and $403 = 4a + 3b$. Then $0 = 4(x-a) + 3(y-b)$. Thus $x-a$ is a multiple of $3$ and $y-b$ is a multiple of $4$. Writing $x-a = 3k$ we see that $y-b$ must be $-4k$. Thus the general solution is as described here (in $\mathbb{Z}$; mild further work to check which are positive is necessary for the list of solutions in $\mathbb{N}$)

Comment: ok but how I could change the solution for natural numbers?

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill, but it couldn't do any harm.

Let
$$\begin{align*}
f : \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z &\rightarrow \mathbb Z \\
(x,y) &\mapsto 20x + 15y
\end{align*}$$

We are looking for solutions to $f(x,y) = 2015$.

Suppose you've found two solutions $(x,y)$ and $(X,Y)$. Then $f(X,Y) - f(x,y) = 0 = f(X-x,Y-y)$ and so $20(X-x) + 15(Y-y) = 0$. Let $n = X-x$ and $m = Y-y$. We can then see that we have:
$$(X,Y) = (x,y) + (n,m)$$
where $20n + 15m = 0$.
Note that any solution to this will add to $(x,y)$ to give another solution.

The point of this is to illustrate that any two solutions are 'separated' by a tuple $(n,m)$ which satisfies the equation $20n + 15m = 0$. This means that if we find just one solution to the original problem, we can generate all possible solutions by allowing ourselves to add any and all solutions for $(n,m)$.

All that is left to determine is the number of solutions to $20n + 15m = 0$. Any two such solutions $(n,m)$ and $(N,M)$ can be added to yield another solution. There is also the solution $(n,m) = (0,0)$. So what we have on our hands is a *group* of $2$-tuples. It is clear that in order to specify a pair $(n,m)$, we only need to specify one of the integers. This uniquely identifies the pair as there will be a unique solution given that one integer. So this group is finitely generated of rank $1$.

All we must do then is find a generating element of the group. $(3,-4)$ must be a generating element because $3$ and $-4$ are coprime and so this $2$-tuple could not have been generated by another element.

All possible $2$-tuple solutions to the null equation are thus $d(3,-4) : d \in \mathbb Z$ and so all possible solutions to the problem are:

$$(x,y) + d(3,-4) : d \in \mathbb Z$$
...where $(x,y)$ is some solution to the problem. $(100,1)$ is an obvious choice. So the complete set of solutions is:

$$(100,1) + d(3,-4) : d \in \mathbb Z$$

Comment: ok but how I could change the solution for natural numbers?

Comment: In this case, pick $(100,1) $ as the starting solution and think about adding $ d (3,-4) $ with $ d \in mathbb Z $ to see which answers will be in the natural numbers. The only solution then is $ d=0$ so $(100,1) $ must be the only final solution for $(x, y) $.

Comment: Oh, that's not true, I have got another solution:
2015=20*97+15*5
Note that 3*20=4*15 but I can't find all integer solutions

Comment: Oh sorry you're right. We can choose $ d $ to be anywhere from $-33$ to $0$ here and $(x, y) $ will be in the natural numbers. So there are 34 solutions if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I can't see how you choose d... maybe any hint?

Comment: I understand that you may not understand my proof as it involves Group Theory, but the final sentence and equation states exactly what the set of solutions is in the integers. Just think about what $ d $ can be if we want the answer in the natural numbers.

Comment: Well (-3, 4) is a solutions of 20n+15m=0
But still no idea why d is in this interval...

Comment: and if d=-33 than we have -99 and it is not natural

Comment: $(100,1) - 33 (3,-4) = (1,133)$. And consequently, $1 \cdot 20 + 133 \cdot 15 = 2015$